# React Hook is called in function "onSubmit" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I have a form, and I wanted to call a hooks `function usePostAddList()` in the component `AddList()` inside the `function onSubmit()`. basically the `usePostAddList()` is to make a `POST` request.

Here's the code for the `AddList()`:

AddList.jsx

```js
export default function AddList() {
..
..
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const data = [
      {
        komoditas,
        areaKota,
        areaProvinsi,
        price,
        tglParsed,
      },
    ]

    // I called it here and it show an error
    usePostAddList(data)
}
..
..
}
```

Reducer/index.js

```js
export function usePostAddList(data) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initState)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST })
    store
      .append("Sheet2", data)
      .then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.ADD_LIST,
          payload: res,
        })
      )
      .catch((e) => {
        return dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.GET_ERRORS,
          payload: e,
        })
      })
  }, [])

  return state
}
```

I have read many solutions like I must write "use" for the name of the function, capitalize the function `AddList`, but still got this error:

```js
React Hook "usePostAddList" is called in function "onSubmit" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

but if I called the `usePostAddList()` like this code below somehow it worked :

AddList.jsx

```js
export default function AddList() {
   const { lists, loading, errors } = usePostAddList("test")

   return (
      ...
   )
}
```

but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Where are your props?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: What is the error? One of the rules of hooks is they have to be called at the top level of the component, so I suspect that's why `usePostAddList()` doesn't error in your second example but it does when it's nested inside of onSubmit.

Comment: so what should I do? I can't call `useReducer` inside a function?

Comment: Are you importing React in your AddList file?

Comment: of course yas..

Comment: Just like in a component, make sure to only call other Hooks unconditionally at the top level of your custom Hook. Meaning you’re building your hook wrong, if you want to execute a function inside it, you need to return it and then use that function in the component using the hook, take a look at how useState works

Comment: could you please write the example?

Comment: Sorry, I’m on my phone rn, another solution is to store your data in a state variable and call your hook outside the submit function passing that variable, your hook will be called everytime your state variable is updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use hooks inside functional components and at the top of your component. Check [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for more information on why.

You can use your custom hook as follows:

```
export default function AddList() {
 const [data,setData] = useState()
 const { lists, loading, errors } = usePostAddList(data)

 return (
  ...
 )
}
```

And update your data at onSubmit function:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault()

 const data = [
  {
    komoditas,
    areaKota,
    areaProvinsi,
    price,
    tglParsed,
   },
 ]

 // Call set data
 setData(data)
}
```

Comment: this approach will call Post request for the first time. wasn't that unnecessary?

Comment: You can add a undefined check to your post request to avoid sending request if the data is undefined.